# Connect ResourceManager for Flink FLIP-6 start new "session job"

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to create a new k8s deployment with a session job; and have one `taskmanager` deployed with a configuration like this in `flink-conf.yaml`:

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: analytics-job
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
```

However, it would seem that my TaskManager refuses to use the port 6123 and always picks a high ports? The analytics job's k8s service looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: analytics-job
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: rpc
    port: 6123
  - name: blob
    port: 6124
  - name: query
    port: 6125
    # nodePort: 30025
  - name: ui
    port: 8081
    # nodePort: 30081
  selector:
    app: analytics
    stack: flink
    component: job-cluster
```

and as you can see I've tried both ClusterIP and NodePort service types. I'd rather have a ClusterIP type since that creates an internal load balancer in front of my k8s Job/`standalone-job.sh` Flink process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In flink-conf.yaml, set

```
high-availability.jobmanager.port: 6123
```

That will bring the resource manager connection back down to the static port you'd like it to be using.

Comment: Thanks !! I was wrongly setting resourcemanager.rpc.port in high availability mode and wondering why that port is not picked up.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't get `nodePorts` like `6123`, `6124`, and `6125` allocated by the Kubernetes master is that there's a port range for `nodePorts` identified by the `--service-node-port-range` option on the [`kube-apiserver`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/). The default for that range is `30000-32767`.

You can just add that flag `--service-node-port-range` to your kubeapi-server configuration typically under `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` with some value like:

```
--service-node-port-range=6000-32767
```

Keep in mind that there could be port overlap with some other services you are running on the node.

As a side node [FLIP-6](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65147077) is a work in progress in [K8s](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-9953) (as of this writing) and you can see it's pretty barebones in Kubernetes in that the jobmanager is not really dynamically creating your taskmanager and allocating resources.

Comment: That's a nice comment so I gave you +1, but it's not the answer. 1) the problem in k8s is not about assigning node port ranges; it's not even about nodeports (why should it be? it has virtual nodes called pods!), 2) my question is "why does the connection to the resource manager fail", but you answer "how can I make lower-numbered ports bindable", which is not the same; because even if I make your change, the connection will still be made on a random high port, as the service's node ports and the actual port in the logs don't correlate

Comment: You also say that "FLIP-6" is a WIP, but that's also not true; if you looked at the linked issue you'll find it's marked as complete. There's also a whole new platform (dA platform/Ververica platform) that builds on the hardness of getting this properly running on your own; which seems to use exactly the same concepts as I'm having trouble with here. Finally, I don't want "service overlap", I want a working deploy without service overlap.

Comment: No problem. In Kubernetes the NodePort is the actual port on the physical machine and the one where your jobmanager and taskmanager would actually bind to. The `port` parameter is just an internal port in the container. Static ports is how `FLIP-6` is supported now in K8s, the dynamic is still a WIP: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-9953. Mesos and Yarn have a more native support. The dA platform works but its a paid solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: I would like to use static ports, but it with HA configured, the resource manager connection is always made over a high port, rather than the static port that I have configured in my service. Also, I think that the issue you link to is long dead and irrelevant to FLIP-6; this is the "passive" variant thereof as far as I've understood it.

Comment: So that's what I'm saying for passive Kubernetes always uses a high port because of `--service-node-port-range`

Comment: I don't mind static high ports. The problem is that the port changes every time you restart the cluster?

Comment: Well not if you use the same Kubernetes services to expose your jobmanager, and taskmanagers.